# Project data set into new objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a really simple question which has troubled me for some time. I have a list of objects containing an array of `Measurements`, where each of these contains a time and multiple values like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5710ed8129c7f31530a537bc"),
    "Measurements" : [ 
        {
            "_t" : "Measurement",
            "_time" : ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
            "Measurement1" : 1
            "Measurement2" : 2
            "Measurement3" : 3
        },
        {
            "_t" : "DataType",
            "_time" : ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
            "Measurement1" : 4
            "Measurement2" : 5
            "Measurement3" : 6
        },
        {
            "_t" : "DataType",
            "_time" : ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
            "Measurement1" : 7
            "Measurement2" : 8
            "Measurement3" : 9
        } ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5710ed8129c7f31530a537cc"),
    "Measurements" : [ 
        {
            "_t" : "Measurement",
            "_time" : ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
            "Measurement1" : 0
....
```

I want to create a query which projects the following data set into the one below. For example, query for `Measurement1` and create an array of objects containing the time and value of `Measurement1` (see below) via mongo aggregation framework.

```
{ "Measurement": [
    {
        "Time": ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
        "Value": 1
    }
    {
        "Time": ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
        "Value": 4
    }
    {
        "Time": ISODate("2016-04-14T12:31:52.584Z"),
        "Value": 7
    }
]}
```

Seems like a pretty standard operation, so I hope you guys can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by first unwinding the `Measurements` array for each doc and then projecting the fields you need and then grouping them back together:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Duplicate each doc, once per Measurements array element
    {$unwind: '$Measurements'},
    // Include and rename the desired fields
    {$project: {
        'Measurements.Time': '$Measurements._time',
        'Measurements.Value': '$Measurements.Measurement1'      
    }},
    // Group the docs back together to reassemble the Measurements array field
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        Measurements: {$push: '$Measurements'}
    }}  
])
```